# android How to sniff extra param value from an intent from a third party app

Tags: android, android-intent, sniffing

Logcat prints 05-09 08:26:17.979 I/ActivityManager( 2257): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com
.com.pkg/.classname (has extras) }
How to know what are those extra key pair values? 
The above log comes from a third party app which i don't have any control.

Answer (score 1):

> How to know what are those extra key pair values?

Call `getExtras()` to get the `Bundle`, then call `keySet()` to see all of the keys.

> The above log comes from a third party app which i don't have any control.

Or, ask the developers of the app that is launching you what they are putting in as extras. Usually it is up to the recipient to document what extras are expected, except for standard actions (e.g., `ACTION_SEND`).

Comment: so that it's clear: is there no straightforward way to see what extras are being passed?